# How do I automate a task on client-side using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call redirectLink function first. Then after the page is redirected and fully loaded. Then I want to call likeButton function. Suggest me a good way to call both functions.

I have tried setTimeout function and $(document).ready too, but it's not working.

```
    function likeButton(){

let likeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.style-scope ytd-toggle-button- 
renderer#like-button');

for(var j=0; j<likeBtn.length; j++)
{
    likeBtn[j].click();
}


}


function loadPage(){

likeButton();
}


  function RedirectLink(){

   var redirects = {
  "https://www.w3schools.com": 
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=topjvXzjdYM"
   };

 var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for(var i = 0;i < aTags.length; i++) {
   aTags[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var url = this.getAttribute("href");

    for (var redirect in redirects) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(redirect);

        if (pattern.test(url)) {
            window.location = redirects[redirect];
            event.preventDefault();
        }



    }
    });
    }



  }

   RedirectLink();
```

This code should redirect some links to another site and then run another function likeButton.

Comment: This is not going to work, when you redirect to another page, all the code in the previous document is gone, and a code of the new page is loaded.

Comment: Is there anyway to run JS on any other site?

Comment: You've to take a look at browser extensions.